# Batch to move files dependent on alphabetical file name?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, robocopy

I'm trying to rewrite this script we use, (server names edited), to solve a problem at work.

```
:asc
if Exist \\SERVER01\import\process\*.asc (goto :SERVER02) ELSE (goto :process)
:SERVER02
if Exist \\SERVER02\import\process\*.asc (goto :end) ELSE (goto :process2)

:process
IF EXIST E:\import\*.asc (
goto :filefound) ELSE (goto :filenotfound)

:filefound
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "e:\import\*.asc" /t:a /o:d /b') do (
  echo %%a
  set file=%%a
goto :break
 )

 :break
 %file%
 robocopy e:\import\ \\SERVER01\import\process\ "%file%" /copy:DAT /mov
goto :end


:process2
IF EXIST E:\import\*.asc (
goto :filefound) ELSE (goto :filenotfound)

:filefound
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "e:\import\*.asc" /t:a /o:d /b') do (
  echo %%a
  set file=%%a
  goto :break2
 )

 :break2
 %file%
 robocopy e:\import\ \\SERVER02\import\process\ %file% /copy:DAT /mov
goto :end

:filenotfound
Echo There are no .asc files at this time)

:end
robocopy \\SERVER01\import\archive\ e:\import\archive\ /copy:DAT /is /mov /xx
robocopy \\SERVER02\import\archive\ e:\import\archive\ /copy:DAT /is /mov /xx
```

Originally this script was set up to balance all files between the two processing applications depending on if one already had a file it was working on, it would give it to the other... but now I need to implement a check on file names and only export certain letter ranges to each processing server.  So I assume this means instead of moving one at a time, we'll just be splitting all `.ASC` files currently sitting in the repository folder at that time and moving half to one server and half to the other (Which then will be picked up one at a time by the application).

We have `.ASC` files which include data for clients, (written to SQL using an old proprietary application).  They are named `CLIENTNAME.asc`, and we have about `200` clients. The use of this software, or its functionality  cannot be changed, so to speed up file processing, we created two servers that run that application. I then I put together a little CMD script that looks at a central repository of those files, and distributes them between each server as a sort of load-balancer.  The issue we've found is, if two files for the same client are processed at the same time, (one went to one server for processing, and another went to the other), it causes an issue on how it imports to SQL.

So the solution in my head is to instead have the script move all `.ASC` files that begin with `A` through `O` to one server, and the those beginning with `L` through `Z` go to the other.  Then I'd mess around with those letter ranges to make sure things are balanced correctly.  This would mean that all client files with the same name would go to the same server, which processes these files one at a time, resolving the duplication issue.

However, I have no idea how to say "IF filename = "A-O".asc move here...", so I'm hoping someone could help me out with that.

As you can see, this batch file runs on the local repository server.  In the `:asc`, we begin by seeing if the first process server, `SERVER01`, has any `.ASC` files on it already.  If so, we go to `:SERVER02`, which checks for the same thing.  If it doesn't currently have any `.ASC` files waiting to be picked up, then it goes to `:process`, where it checks if the local repository folder, `E:\import`, has any .`ASC` files waiting to be distributed.  If so, it will move that file to `SERVER01` to be processed.  Then the script ends by copying some archive files, (the `.ASC` files that have been processed), back to the repository server.  Then there's a similar thing that happens in ":process2", but moves them to `SERVER02` to be processed instead.  Overall, this gives a slight load balancing between the two.

I understand the script is super messy, and can certainly be trimmed down with more strings rather than a different function for each server path, but hopefully you can get the general idea.

Comment: You probably need to loop over A..O. See `help for`. Basically the for loop supplies the letter and the body uses the argument as `"%%L*.asc"` to find any of those files. That or you convert the whole thing to PowerShell and use some linq foo.

Comment: Or you could use `findstr.exe`, with for example `dir "e:\import\*.asc" /t:a /o:d /b 2^>nul ^| findstr.exe /b /i /r "[A-O]"`.

Comment: I like @Compo's idea better than mine.

Comment: I presume, that there's a relatively even mix of files/client names beginning with the first fifteen letters of the alphabet, compared with the last eleven! If not you're not really balancing any load.

Comment: Yeah, there will certainly need to be a bit of messing around with the range of letters... I'd like to simply say there are X clients A-O and also X client P-Z, but on top of that, some clients are larger than others and take longer to process, so even an equal number of clients isn't ideal... that's why originally it was great to simply pass on the next file based on whatever process server was empty, but now I need to find a way to make sure all files from the same client get moved together, which is throwing a wrench in everything as far as load balancing.

Comment: When the script runs, there can be only one (1) CLIENTNAME.asc file in `E:\import\`. It cannot send the same client to two servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An attempt at doing this in Powershell - this will copy everything in A-O at once:

```
# Get the list of ASC files
$LocalFiles = Get-ChildItem "e:\import\*.asc"

# Check if any files exist
if (!$LocalFiles){Write-Output 'There are no .asc files at this time';break}

# Move the files based on first letter of the file name
$LocalFiles | Where Name -Match '^[A-O].*' | Move-Item -Destination \\SERVER01\import\process\ -Verbose
$LocalFiles | Where Name -Match '^[P-Z].*' | Move-Item -Destination \\SERVER02\import\process\ -Verbose
```

If the first letter is not always capitalized, use `[A-Oa-o]` instead.

If you need to keep your timestamps or attributes, you will need to use robocopy instead still like so:

```
$LocalFiles | Where Name -Match '^[A-O].*' | 
  foreach { robocopy src dst $_.name [...] }
```